chilled-water residential AC blowing too cold
I'm living in UAE, where most properties have air condition on a common chilled-water line.
The chilled water line is around 7C, so when the AC units engage, they blow a very very cold stream of air into the rooms.
Especially in the bedroom, it makes it near impossible to sleep, when you get hit with a 7C wind in your face every hour or so.
Even with a multiple-speed unit, when I set it on the lowest speed, it just creates a "curtain" of cold air dripping from the unit, instead of blowing the cold air further in the room (because it only reduces the fan, but still pushing 7C air in the room).
Since the chilled-water line is from the building, I cannot regulate the temperature inside the line. Anyone has some idea of what solution I could use to make the air being pushed in the room not so cold? (budget not an issue, and I'm able to replace anything inside the home)
Note: to be clear, the problem is not the temperature in the room. The rooms are at 24C exactly like the thermostat is set to. The problem is the temperature of the stream of air being pushed inside the rooms, that is way below the comfortable temperature

a simple plastic curtain will disperse the air flow

Paradoxically, setting the fan speed higher will (marginally) increase the air temp coming out of the heat exchanger and improve air mixing. In turn improving comfort.
Another option is to add some fans and/or air deflectors/ducts to better direct the cold air and make it mix with the room air before you can feel it.

Mixing is key, +1. Blowing fast horizontally might help. Fixing the vanes so they direct the air sensibly is important, with brute force if the controls are inadequate. In labs where the changing cold draught is a problem I've rigged strip curtains hanging in the horizontal airflow they force some mixing and deflect some of the air down

anyone already experimented with just putting some heating elements inside the vents to warm up a little the air the coil is producing before it enters the room (heating from the chilled-water 7C to something more comfortable like 15-18C but that will still cool the room)

It seems to me that your room is set to 24°C precisely because the cold stream is blowing in.  If you try to reduce the flow, it will adversely affect the temperature in your room.
What you want to do is to divert it up so that it mixes with warm air before settling down.  If that's not workable then use a fan to divert it sideways, away from the bed.
In the end though, most AC's will give this effect. The rest of the air in the room is warm when compared to the air being blown in.  So, you are likely to feel the difference.
What works for us is to have the vents on the wall, above the bedhead. We set the fan at medium speed and the air then blows over us before mixing and settling down.

in other properties that I have, where the AC is a split unit and I can control the compressor, I can make the AC blow some air that is around 15-18C, which will cool down the room at 24C without problems, but not feel so uncomfortable.
The problem is the chilled-water temperature.
I was even thinking to jurry-rig some heating coil around the incoming chilled-water line to warm it up, but I think this might affect the whole building and get me in troubles
